# RadGrid with doubleclick and click behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a scenario in which there is a master and seperate detail grid. Double clicking on the master should open an edit form. Single click should change te selected row and rebind the detail grid.

The master grid has the following client events:

```
    var hasChanges, inputs, dropdowns, editedRow;
    var isDoubleClick = false;
    var clickHandler = null;
    var ClickedDataKey = null;

    function RowClickHoofdscenario(sender, args) {
        ClickedDataKey = args._dataKeyValues.Id;
        isDoubleClick = false;
        if (clickHandler) {
            window.clearTimeout(clickHandler);
            clickHandler = null;
        }
        clickHandler = window.setTimeout(ActualClick(args), 100);
    }

    function RowDblClickHoofdscenario(sender, args) {
        isDoubleClick = true;
        if (clickHandler) {
            window.clearTimeout(clickHandler);
            clickHandler = null;
        }
        clickHandler = window.setTimeout(ActualClick(args), 100);
    }

    function ActualClick(eventArgs) {

        if (isDoubleClick) {
            if (editedRow && hasChanges) {
                hasChanges = false;
                if (confirm("Wijzigingen opslaan?")) {
                    $find("<%= rgHoofdscenarios.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().updateItem(editedRow);
                }
            }
            else {
                editedRow = eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical();
                $find("<%= rgHoofdscenarios.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().editItem(editedRow);
            }
        }
        else {
           ** implement refresh here ** (added this line in StackOverflow ;) )
        }
    }
```

How do I implement the selected row change? I have tried an ajax on OnRowSelected that does a server Rebind of the detail grid. But it shows the detail content of the previous selection.